# simulate mouse click on link advanced (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, simulate

Now for few days I'm looking for a way to click on a link inside website programmatically!

now my function what I found was implemented with no problems

```
function simulateClick(x, y) 
{
    var clickEvent= document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0,0, 0, x, y,    false, false,false, false, 0, null);
    document.elementFromPoint(x, y).dispatchEvent(clickEvent);    
}
```

The thing is it works like a charm when there are links as **DOM elements** like embed inside a website, but this don't work on outer links (I don't know how to explain) they are on site but dynamically generated in like iframe or something, similar to ads are being displayed, I need to be able to click on all links on website any chance I can simulate a click on those elements with Javascript ? or other client side language?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: If the link is inside an iframe and the code is running in the context of the site hosting the iframe, JavaScript is not going to be able to click it because of the same origin policy.

Comment: It's impossible to implement the following code if the content of the iframe comes from other website/protocol/port. You can only try to do this by trying to access the iframe `contentWindow` or `contentDocument` (I don't remember which one) **if and only if** the domain, port and protocol are the same. It's the only way.

Comment: Similar to how ads are displayed? You don't say? :P

Comment: I smell a money making script

Comment: not same origin ! As Im talking about iframes !

it's script yes but it's more for direct downloads*, you know sites where are  10 banners of download now etc ?! Now your on right track what I'm trying to pull off ! ;)

Comment: You can't 'click' on links outside the page's [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Thank god